# Differences using ImageJ and python package pyclesperanto_prototype to open up images

Tags: python, imagej, imread

I am trying to open up an image that I am able to open up using imageJ but I seem to be getting a differnet image when I use pycelspranto_protype versus imageJ the image is 10 zstacks in three 3 different channels and 1926 by 1926 pixels for each image. This gives multichannel_image a shape of (10, 1926, 1926, 3) which seems correct. However the code below seems to
yield the incorrect first image when I want the imageJ/correct second image.

```
from skimage import data
from skimage import io
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from skimage.transform import warp
from skimage.feature import ORB, match_descriptors
from skimage.transform import AffineTransform, estimate_transform
import pyclesperanto_prototype as cle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.feature import match_descriptors, plot_matches, SIFT
from skimage import transform

multichannel_image = imread("C:\\Users\\antho\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NerettiLab\\Montage-000-000_reduced\\img001.ome.tif")

print(multichannel_image.shape)
cle.imshow(multichannel_image[5,:,:,1], labels=True)
```

[image: Image by pyclesperanto_prototype]

[image: Correct ImageJ image]